# Chef - Remove identical code multiple recipes

Tags: ruby, chef-infra

I'm relatively new to Chef/Ruby, and I'm trying clean up some old code from an old colleague. I have three recipes:

1. cookbook/providers/domain.rb
2. cookbook/providers/domaincontroller.rb
3. cookbook/providers/rename.rb

There's an identical ruby code block in each of these:

```
def computer_exists?
  comp = Mixlib::ShellOut.new('powershell.exe -command \"get-wmiobject -class win32_computersystem -computername . | select domain\"').run_command
  comp.stdout.include?(new_resource.name) || comp.stdout.include?(new_resource.name.upcase)
end
```

Is there a way I can wrap this block of code into a attribute, or something along those lines, so that we're not constantly re-writing the same 4 lines in each of the recipes?

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [libaries](https://docs.chef.io/libraries.html).

You should be able to dump that exact code in a new file under `libraries` (e.g. `cookbook/libraries/helper.rb`) and then call `computer_exists?` from anywhere.